# Dynamic radio button value retrieval

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, dynamic-controls

```
this.Controls.Add(new CheckBox{ Checked = true; })
```

When I add this in the `page_load`. It works, it adds the checkbox and it is visible.

A little different approach:

```
var button = new CheckBox{ Checked = true; } 
globals.button = button;
this.Controls.Add(button);
```

Globals is a class with a checkbox property on which I want to set the checkbox in the hope of retrieving it's a data after pressing a button.

```
public static CheckBox button { get; set; }
```

However, when a button is pressed, the control has vanished of my screen and the button in my globals class has not been updated with any changes I have made to the checkbox.

How can I change the checked state of a checkbox and catch it's current state when I perform a button.click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-create dynamic controls on every postback, they wont magically re-appear because every request is a new instance of the `Page` class.

See my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434521/adding-a-user-control-to-a-page-programatically-while-preserving-controls-alread) post on this subject, it is using a user control but the idea is just the same.

[And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280928/asp-net-event-handler-when-click-on-link-button-dynamically/6281050#6281050)

**You must add the control before Page_Load**

I normally do it in the overridden `CreateChildControls` but some people use `Page_Init`.

see [this article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

***Update***

This is a very simple way to add the checkbox dynamically, that preserves state/value when the button is clicked.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:Button OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Click Me" />

        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class Test : Page
{
    private CheckBox MyCheckBox { get; set; }
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

        this.MyCheckBox = new CheckBox() { Checked = true };
        this.ph.Controls.Add(this.MyCheckBox);
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var someValue = this.MyCheckBox.Checked;
        this.lbl.Text = someValue ? "Checked" : "Not Checked";
    }

}
```

Comment: adding the controls again isn't the problem. Getting the value when I changed it on a button click is my problem.

Comment: you said `However, when a button is pressed, the control has vanished of my screen ` - this would indicate you did not re-add the control in each postback, if it isnt added you cant get the value

Comment: I want to get the value from the checkbox set in the globals class.

Comment: From where ? the button only exists within that one request, once that request has finished the button is gone, you can't store it and retrieve it later. If you need to store a value to use later, you could use `Session` or `Application`.

Comment: So I can't store the button in a different class and access it from there after I did a postback?
I'm quite sure I have done this before with textbox's .. but I lost that project`.  PS. I can't put the control creation in OnInit or CreateChildControl since it's dependent on the value of a drop down box

Comment: You could store it in the globals class, as long as you used it within the same request, but whats the point, you already have a reference to the control within the page so why do you need to do this ?

Comment: I still dont exactly understand how this works. But it does work!  Thank you for your answer and time

Answer (score 0):

If dynamic controls are created in the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method they will not return the changes the user made.

The reason you're having problems is the ASP.Net view state is created before the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method is called. The ASP.Net view state hold what controls are on the page and their values. The `Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)` method is called before the ASP.Net view state is created. By creating the controls in the `Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)` method will return what the user enter, furthermore the controls will only need to be created if the page isn't a post back.

If you can't create the controls in the `Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)` method for some reason, you will edit to change the ASP.Net view state the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

If you need to create the controls in the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method this question should help [How to Persist Variable on Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222999/how-to-persist-variable-on-postback)